# GegorianCalendar is giving me 2018 for int month = calendar.get(Calendar.FEBUARY)

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

So Im working on an Calendar programm and to change the Months im asking for the int of the month.

If I type calendar.get(Calendar.JANUARY) i get 1 as return, which is correct because first month. But if I type calendar.get(Calendar.FEBUARY) i get 2018 in respond which of course is wrong. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
int month = cal1.get(Calendar.JANUARY);
int month2 = cal1.get(Calendar.FEBRUARY);
int year = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: The `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` classes are long outdated, poorly designed, cumbersome to work with and sometimes confusing, as you have experienced. Allow me to suggest you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

[T.J. Crowder’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434540/5772882) is correct. Allow me to supply the **real, good and modern** solution to your problem.

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Atlantic/Stanley"));
    // 2018-05-21T05:02:23.942763-03:00[Atlantic/Stanley]
    Month monthEnum = zdt.getMonth(); // MAY
    int monthNumber = zdt.getMonthValue(); // 5
    int year = zdt.getYear(); // 2018
```

I ran the code just now and have given results in comments after each code line. Please put your desired time zone where I have put Atlantic/Stanley since the month does not change at the same point in time in different time zones. Do you agree with me that this code is clearer and more natural and leaves less room for confusion? BTW, if you’re only interested in the date, not the time of day, use `LocalDate` instead of `ZonedDateTime`, the rest of the code will be the same.

To get the numbers of specific months:

```
    int januaryNumber = Month.JANUARY.getValue(); // 1
    int februaryNumber = Month.FEBRUARY.getValue(); // 2
```

### What happened in your code?

As T.J. Crowder has already said, `Calendar.get` expects a *field number*, for example `Calendar.MONTH` or `Calendar.YEAR`. `Calendar.JANUARY` is 0. Zero?! It’s another confusing thing about `Calendar`, month numbers are 0-based, that is, they go from 0 for January through 11 for December. Anyway, 0 is also the field number of `Calendar.ERA`. `GregorianCalendar` uses 0 for BC (or more religion neutral: BCE for before common era) and 1 for AD (CE, common era). Since your date is in the common era, you get 1. Which, by the way, would have been incorrect for month of January since months are 0-based.

Similarly, `Calendar.FEBRUARY` equals 1 and coincides with field number `Calendar.YEAR`, which I why you got the year.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Question: Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: Excellent. I haven't used `java.time` (because I haven't done virtually any Java programming in the last few years) so couldn't include this in my answer. I should have at least mentioned `java.time`, though, I do know *about* it...

Comment: Uhhh that is a very nice Solution. Sadly my Java-Teacher is really annoying and forces us to use GregorianCalendar. But she overall just uses really old APIs, like we are not allowed to use JavaFX even if we can use it

Comment: Das finde ich Schade, @SarahSparda. Such teachers exist, it makes me wonder. Maybe she just cannot find the time to learn the new APIs herself. Speculation, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`Calendar#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) gets a **field** value. [`Calendar.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) is not a field number, it's a potential field *value*. The only static fields in `Calendar` that you use with `get` (and `set`) are the ones whose descriptions start with "Field number for `get` and `set`...".

To get the month, use `cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)`.

The `Calendar` API is...unfortunate, not least because it predates enums and so `int` was used for `get`/`set`'s field identifier parameter where an enum was really needed. While `get` takes an `int`, and `Calendar.JANUARY` is an `int`, they're `int`s in different domains. See [Ole V.V.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444464/157247) for the modern, dramatically-improved alternative: `java.time`.

Comment: Do you have an Idea how I could ask for the month value?

Comment: @SarahSparda - I answered that in the second paragraph above: *"To get the month, use `cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)`."*