# Difference between 2 calendar instances giving inconsistent answers

Tags: java, calendar, java-7, days

I'm using jdk 1.7 and using the Calendar class to calculate the difference between 2 dates. I'm using the below code but it gives inconsistent results. Meaning sometimes it's correct but sometimes it's off by a day or something and there is no pattern to it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {

        System.out.println(calculateDays());
    }

    private static long calculateDays() {
        long days_past_due;
           Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
           Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal1.set(2013, 12, 1);
           cal2.set(2013, 12, 30);
           days_past_due = getDifference(cal1, cal2, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        return days_past_due;
    }

    public static long getDifference(Calendar b, Calendar a, TimeUnit units) 
    {

        return units.convert(b.getTimeInMillis() - a.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Examples:

```
Example 1: cal1.set(2013, 12, 1);
           cal2.set(2013, 12, 1);
           Answer returned: 0 (Correct)
Example 2: cal1.set(2013, 12, 1);
           al2.set(2013, 12, 2);
           Answer returned: -1 (Correct)
Example 3: cal1.set(2013, 11, 30);
           cal2.set(2013, 12, 1);
           Answer returned: -2 (Incorrect)
Example 4: cal1.set(2013, 8, 31);
           cal2.set(2013, 8, 31);
           Answer returned: 0 (Correct)
Example 5: cal1.set(2013, 8, 31);
           cal2.set(2013, 9, 1);
           Answer returned: 0 (Incorrect)
Example 6: cal1.set(2013, 6, 30);
           cal2.set(2013, 6, 30);
           Answer returned: 0 (Correct)
Example 7: cal1.set(2013, 6, 30);
           cal2.set(2013, 7, 1);
           Answer returned: -2 (Incorrect)
```

What is that I'm doing incorrectly here?

Comment: this might be obvious...but all of the incorrect calculations span across two different months. maybe thats the cause?

Comment: Month numbers are zero-based in `Calendar`.

Comment: also why convert milliseconds to milliseconds?

Comment: Your way of calculating the difference also will not work correctly across transitions to and from summer time (DST). `Calendar` can do that if you know how, but it’s cumbersome. I wouldn’t bother. I would add [the ThreeTen backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to my project and use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and everything would be straightforward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: @ScaryWombat The code in the question is converting milliseconds to days since `units` is `DAYS` in the call to `getDifference`. It’s not the easiest nor the correct way, though.

Comment: thanks for your comments. @OleV.V. what would be the easier way to do it then? Using the same Calendar class

Comment: There is no easier way using the `Calendar` class. At least not if it should also be a correct way.

Comment: What I meant with “It’s not the easiest …” was, to convert between two time units I find it a bit simpler to do `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffInMillis)`. It’s less general, of course, and worse, it still doesn’t handle summer time transitions correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You should be using `LocalDate` with sane counting, instead of the troublesome `Calendar` class.

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2013 , 11 , 30 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2013 , 12 , 1 )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/LSVcyK).

> 1

## Crazy counting

You seem to be unaware of the crazy counting used in the terrible `Calendar` class: 0-11 for months January-December.

So `cal1.set(2013, 11, 30)` to `cal2.set(2013, 12, 1)` means October 30 to November 1, which is indeed two days, accounting for October 31. You apparently thought of this incorrectly as November 30 to December 1, but no.

This is [index-counting, zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). Unfortunately, index-counting shows up all too often with some programmers inappropriately using what made sense with primitive arrays or memory-jumping in systems programming or old-school C-style programming. In common business apps with modern languages, ordinal-counting usually makes more sense. For example, thinking of January as first month, month 1, and December as twelfth month, month 12.

## java.time

Fortunately, we have the *java.time* classes now. There is no reason for you to ever use the awful mess that is the legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

For your use with Java 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project linked in the bullets at bottom below.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `ChronoUnit.DAYS`

To count elapsed days, use the `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for `Calendar#set(int,int,int)` says (my emphasis)

> Parameters:
>
> year - the value used to set the YEAR calendar field.
>
> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. ***Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.***
>
> date - the value used to set the DAY_OF_MONTH calendar field.

If you re-examine your examples with this in mind, and remember that dates get "normalized" (i.e. if you specify the 13th month it becomes the first month of the following year), you'll find that all the calculated differences are actually correct.

Comment: when I put the first date as (2014, 2 , 10) March 10th, 2014 and the second date as (2014, 2, 8) March 8th 2014, it gives me the result as 1. When in fact it should be 2. Why did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the easier way to do it then? Using the same Calendar class

There is no easier way using `Calendar`. There is a more cumbersome ad error-prone way.

First you need to initialize your two `Calendar` objects correctly:

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.clear();
    cal2.clear();
    cal1.set(2013, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 30);
    cal2.set(2013, Calendar.DECEMBER, 1);
```

A `Calendar` object despite its name represents a date, a time of day, a time zone and a calendar system. When we want to use it for a date in the Gregorian calendar in a time zone alone, we need to clear the fields first to get rid of the time of day, or it will interfere with the calculations to follow. Next use the named constants of the `Calendar` class for the months of the dates you wish to set to reduce confusion.

Second, to have `Calendar` take transitions to and from summer time (DST) and other anomalies into account there is no other way than adding the days and seeing when we are there — it’s the backward way of doing it:

```
    if (cal1.before(cal2)) {
        int daysPastDue = 0;
        while (! cal1.after(cal2)) {
            daysPastDue++;
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        // Now cal1 is after cal2, so we’ve counted 1 day too many. Compensate:
        daysPastDue--;
        System.out.println("Answer returned: " + daysPastDue);
    }
```

This prints:

> Answer returned: 1

I certainly don’t encourage doing it the way I have shown. It’s relatively many lines of code, and it’s fairly easy to forget one detail and get a wrong result or make an off-by-one error. Upgrade to Java 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 if you can. If you cannot, [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546673/5772882) works nicely with the ThreeTen Backport library too, see his bullet about Java SE 6 and Java SE 7.

PS: While the `TimeUnit` enum is great for conversions between anything from microseconds to hours, don’t use it for days, at least not in this case. `TimeUnit.DAYS` counts 24 hours, while days in the calendar may be 23, 24 or 25 hours and occasionally have yet other lengths.