# Why isn't Date object representing date in my JVM's timezone?

Tags: java, time, timezone

I have UTC date and I need to create Date object with exact same value as UTC ( legacy reasons ).

I have managed to do it:

```
String date = "2012-05-05 12:13:14";
TemporalAccessor formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        .parse(date);
Instant instant = Instant.from(
        formatter
); //
ZonedDateTime zdf = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant,ZoneId.of("UTC"));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(zdf.getYear(),zdf.getMonthValue(),zdf.getDayOfMonth(),zdf.getHour(),zdf.getMinute(),zdf.getSecond());
Date dt = calendar.getTime();

Date d2 = Date.from(instant);
```

However, what bothers me -

When I create date object, it should display the date in my JVM's default timezone. But here `dt` has exact same value as my input UTC date, but `dt2` has same date represented in my default timezone, why did this happen? Why is one not converted and another is?

Thanks for explaining!

Comment: A `java.util.Date` doesn't have a time zone at all. It's *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Ignore the result of calling `Date.toString()` - the fact that that converts the value to the local time zone is just annoying :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Is Date.toString() called even when inspecting variables during debugging? I checked the value of objects that way

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried printing it and both print Different values, so one is converted and another isnt

Comment: Well `dt` is being created as "2012-05-05 12:13:14 in the system time zone", because you've called `Calendar.getInstance()` which uses the system time zone. Whereas `d2` is 2012-05-05 12:13:14 in UTC. So yes, I'm not surprised they're doing different things, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Careful.  `zdf.getMonthValue()` [returns a value from 1 to 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getMonthValue%28%29), but [Calendar.set expects a value from 0 to 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,int,int,int,int,int%29).

Comment: This question was asked a couple of days ago, differently worded but with the same code snippet. I wrote a longish answer. Now it seems that that question has been deleted (I cannot find it) and then posted anew. I’m confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preserving the hour of day versus preserving the moment

I’ll explain the central lines one by one.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This creates a `Calendar` with the same time zone as your JVM’s default time zone. Unlike `Date` a `Calendar` *has* got a time zone.

```
    calendar.set(zdf.getYear(),zdf.getMonthValue(),zdf.getDayOfMonth(),
            zdf.getHour(),zdf.getMinute(),zdf.getSecond());
```

This sets your `Calendar` to the same *wall clock time* as your `ZonedDateTime`, namely 12:13:14. Since the `ZonedDateTime` and the `Calendar` have different time zones (UTC and your local time zone, respectively), this results in a different moment.

Also @VGR is correct: While the date of the `ZonedDateTIme` was in May (month 5), you are setting the `Calendar` month to June because `Calendar` months are confusingly 0-based, from 0 for January through 11 for December.

```
    Date d2 = Date.from(instant);
```

This is the correct conversion from `Instant` to `Date` and gives you the same point in time, the same moment as the `Instant`. And therefore *not* the same moment as the `Calendar` and `dt`.

And it was probably understood in your question, but for anyone reading along I would like to state directly: `Date` and `Calendar` are poorly designed and long outdated. You should not use them except when necessary for interacting with a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to upgrade just now. For all other uses stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Links

- [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s code blog
- Stack Overflow question: [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- As others said, a `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC. Its `toString` method lies to you by dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating is poorly-formatted string. One of *many* reasons to never use this class.
- Do not waste you time on trying to understand the terrible classes `Date` & `Calendar`. They are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), to be avoided.
- Use only [*java.time* classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) for all your [date-time handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## Details

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420963/642706) is correct and should be accepted. I'll add a few thoughts.

You are mixing the terrible legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`) with their modern replacements (`Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`). **Do not mix these.** The legacy classes are entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

There is no need to ever use `Date` or `Calendar` again. **Do not waste your time trying to understand them.** They were replaced for a reason – many reasons, actually. Use your brains and time for more productive work.

If you must use the legacy classes to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert to-and-fro by calling the new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old classes. Perform your business logic, data exchange, and data storage all using the *java.time* classes.

The `java.util.Date` class is replaced by `Instant`.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;     // From  modern to legacy.
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;             // From legacy to modern.
```

The `Calendar` class, or rather its commonly used subclass [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), is replaced by `ZonedDateTime`. Assuming your `Calendar` object is really a `GregorianCalendar` underneath, you can cast, then convert.

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( zonedDateTime ) ;                        // From  modern to legacy.
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ( (GregorianCalendar) c ).toZonedDateTime() ;   // From legacy to modern.
```

Here is a chart mapping the legacy classes to the modern ones.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy & modern) and in standard SQL.]