# Android - GregorianCalendar displays wrong month

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gregorian-calendar

I tried searching the internet and found a lot of questions on StackOverlflow somewhat regarding the same topic, but couldn't find anything that I was able to understand...

So, I have this data class that contains a dateOfOrigin of type GregorianCalendar. Using gson I convert all json and return an Observable array with all locations. Inside the json file, I added the dateOfOrigin as an object like so:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Fuse",
    "image": "fuse.jpg",
    "street": "Blaesstraat 208",
    "city": "Brussels Hoofdstedelijk Gewest",
    "zip": 1000,
    "date_of_origin": {"year":1994,"month":4,"dayOfMonth":16},
    "parking": true
}
```

And this is what my data class looks like:

```
data class Location (
    val id : Int,
    val name : String,
    val image : String,
    val street : String,
    val city : String,
    val zip : Int,
    @SerializedName("date_of_origin")
    val originDate : GregorianCalendar?,
    val parking : Boolean = true,
    var imageBitmap : Bitmap? = null
)
```

Whenever I try to set the dateText like this:

```
originDate?.let {
    dateText = "${it.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)} ${it.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())} ${it.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"

    dateText = resources.getString(R.string.origin_date, dateText)
}
```

It outputs `16 May 1994` instead of `16 Apr 1994`

I'm not able to figure out how to fix this...

**EDIT**
Subtracting 1 from the month seems to fix the problem for most cases. Still, I have one result that is supposed to output `30 Jan 2016` but displays `1 Feb 2016`.

```
"date_of_origin": {"year":2016,"month":1,"dayOfMonth":30}
```

Comment: Calender.MONTH starts at 0 (for January, [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH)), so you have to subtract one to get the right date.

Comment: hello, i think it's duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar). That's because android calendar MONTH starts from 0 position

Comment: Use `java.time`...

Comment: the real question is : is this even a bug or a problem ? it's not displaying what you THINK it should in terms of months, but that doesn't mean that it's wrong, maybe it's the correct date :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody On the other hand, it is not definitely intuitive and that is IMHO what matters the most.

Comment: what isn't intuitive @Hawklike ? the fact that you're parsing json data and displaying it like you're receiving it ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Starting counting the months from 0, as it is not what we are used to doing in real life.

Comment: it doesn't really matter here how intuitive it is (or isn't) as for this case it works fine, it just wasn't the output OP was expecting, but it doesn't make it wrong @Hawklike

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GregorianCalendar` represents months with numbers in the range from `0` to `11`. This means that the number `0` is represented as January and `11` is represented as of December.

Therefore you need to subtract `1` if your API is not using the same logic as the Java implementation.

**Updated:**
`GregorianCalendar(2016, 1, 30)` is understood as 30th of February. This is internally converted to 1st of March, therefore when you subtract one month from the date, you get 1st of February. You need to create an instance of `GregorianCalendar` class already with the subtracted month number, ie. January as 0, February as 1 and so on.

Comment: there's no reason to use Joda Time

Comment: also, wouldn't you need to `subtract` instead of `add` ?

Comment: i don't think the last part of your answer is necessary at all really, as both the api and the implementation are using the same logic - just because it isn't displaying what OP thought it would doesn't actually make it wrong in this case

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand why it would be converted internally to 1st of March though... Tried creating an instance of GregorianCalendar as follows but still returns 1st of Feb instead of 30th of Feb: originDate?.let { val d = GregorianCalendar(it.get(Calendar.YEAR), it.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1, it.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) //.... }

Comment: Because the 30th of February is nonsense. Specifically, the year 2016 is a leap year, so February has 29 days. Therefore the 30th of February is converted to 1st of March (overflows).

Comment: To your new implementation - it doesn't change anything. You need to create `originDate` with subtracted month from scratch. In other words, in code where you create an instance of `GregorianCalendar` for the first time, in that particular place you have to pass subtracted month as one the constructor arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214211/discussion-between-hawklike-and-dantec).

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Hawklike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888308/642706) is correct. You were tricked by the crazy month-numbering scheme employed by the `GregorianCalendar` class. One of many reasons to avoid this class.

---

## tl;dr

```
myGregCal  
.toZonedDateTime()                           // Convert from obsolete `GregorianCalendar` class to modern `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class.
.toLocalDate()                               // Extract the date portion, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.format(                                     // Generate text representing the value of this date-time object.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )   // Automatically localize.
    .withLocale(                             // Specify a locale for the human language and cultural norms used in localization. 
        Locale.UK
    )
)
```

> 23 Jan 2021

## Details

Never use `GregorianCalendar`. This class is part of the date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

If you must interoperate with code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

[`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) was replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;  // From legacy class to modern class.
```

Going the other direction.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

Or break that int multiple parts.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

Or use month number rather than `Month` enum for the month. Notice that *java.time* uses sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December, unlike `GregorianCalendar`.

```
LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 )  // Same effect as Month.JANUARY.
```

To generate text, use `DateTimeFormatter` class. Your desired format happens to match that of localized format used in the UK. So let *java.time* automatically localize for you by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt2.toLocalDate().format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oO1v3f).

> 23 Jan 2021

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]