# Get Date of Specific Week

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to get the start and end date of specific week of a month. However the date is incorrect. Can anyone identify what's the issue ?

```
public class DateUtils
{
   getWeeklyDateList(2020,5, 3);

  public static void getWeeklyDateList(int year, int month, int week)
  {
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
      // setting year, month, week
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
      calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,week);

    // setting day of week to first --> Sunday
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

    int year1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // setting day of week to last --> Saturday
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);

    int year7 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month7 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day7 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Log.e("date_start", String.valueOf(year1) + "-" + String.valueOf(month1) + "-" + String.valueOf(day1));
    Log.e("date_end", String.valueOf(year7) + "-" + String.valueOf(month7) + "-" + String.valueOf(day7));
} }
```

Comment: Are you expecting start to be 2020-6-14 and end 2020-6-20? What are you getting instead? Please remember, *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.* From [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

If you want to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, it can be done with this simple method:

```
private static WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.forLanguageTag("ne-NP"));

public static void getWeeklyDateList(int year, Month month, int week) {
    LocalDate someDateInTheWeek = LocalDate.of(year, month, 10).with(wf.weekOfMonth(), week);
    LocalDate start = someDateInTheWeek.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1);
    LocalDate end = someDateInTheWeek.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 7);

    System.out.println("date_start: " + start);
    System.out.println("date_end:   " + end);
}
```

Trying it out with your example arguments:

```
    getWeeklyDateList(2020, Month.JUNE, 3);
```

Output is:

> ```
> date_start: 2020-06-14
> date_end:   2020-06-20
> ```

How it works:

First, weeks are defined differently in different cultures. In Nepal (since you give Kathmandu, Nepal as your location) weeks start on Sunday and are numbered in a way where the 1st of the month is in week 1 of the month. To handle this week scheme I am initializing a `WeekFields` object for Nepalese culture.

`LocalDate` is the java.time class for a date without time of day. I don’t think it matters which day of the month I pick as a starting point; I took the 10th. From that date I get a date in the correct week, using the `WeekFields` object and the supplied week number. From there in turn I get the first and the last day of the week, again according to the Nepalese definition of weeks: from Sunday June 14 through Saturday June 20 2020.

What went wrong in your code I cannot tell. In any case the `Calendar` class you used is poorly designed and long outdated. It also default uses the default locale of the JVM for its week definition, which may have given you a different week scheme from what you wanted. A final point that may have confused you: `Calendar` unnaturally numbers months from 0 for January through 11 for December. So when you specified 5, you got June (not May). You printed out the month numbers of your result dates, which probably again printed 5 (not 6) for June.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Question: Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Comment: Most of your as well as Basil Bourque's answers on the topic of date/time are like a compact chapter on date & time. It not only solves the problem but also helps one learn about the nitty-gritty of old and new date & time API. I must say that the credit of most my knowledge about the modern date & time API goes to both of you.

Comment: Thanks, @ArvindKumarAvinash, for the nice words. They matter.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this line,
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

this can take month to previous month if week starts in previous one. If there is a month difference then this is the problem.

Comment: So how can we get 1st and last date of that week. In the above code?

Comment: I think Ole V.V. solution is perfect in this case.But if you still have to use this solution you can loop through after setting year and month. like
        while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month)  
then check for sundays according to weeks.